# How to enable JSONP for WMS GetFeatureInfo on GeoServer 2.6.2

Tags: geoserver, wms

calling GetCapabilities reports text/javascript for JSONP is not available for GetFeatureInfo.  Other types are included in the list.

according to GeoServer docs @ http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/reference.html this should be possible

this is a fresh install of geoserver 2.6.2 running as a service on Windows 8.1

we set ENABLE_JSONP true in\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\web.xml and restarted the GeoServer serveice

wrapper.log reports as follows;

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 | org.geowebcache.mime.MimeException: Unsupported format request: text/javascript
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geowebcache.mime.MimeType.createFromFormat(MimeType.java:134)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getInfoMimeTypes(GeoServerTileLayer.java:1105)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geowebcache.service.wms.WMSGetCapabilities.capabilityRequestGetFeatureInfo(WMSGetCapabilities.java:303)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geowebcache.service.wms.WMSGetCapabilities.capability(WMSGetCapabilities.java:215)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geowebcache.service.wms.WMSGetCapabilities.generateGetCapabilities(WMSGetCapabilities.java:125)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geowebcache.service.wms.WMSGetCapabilities.writeResponse(WMSGetCapabilities.java:86)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geowebcache.service.wms.WMSService.handleRequest(WMSService.java:288)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geowebcache.service.wms.WMSService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$85c0e55b.invoke(<generated>)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.gwc.config.GWCServiceEnablementInterceptor.invoke(GWCServiceEnablementInterceptor.java:47)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geowebcache.service.wms.WMSService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$e0331eae.handleRequest(<generated>)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher.handleServiceRequest(GeoWebCacheDispatcher.java:344)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher.handleRequestInternal(GeoWebCacheDispatcher.java:254)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.gwc.dispatch.GwcServiceProxy.dispatch(GwcServiceProxy.java:98)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:792)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:274)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1093)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:83)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:135)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:76)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.vfny.geoserver.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:726)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:206)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:828)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:514)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/03/02 12:38:16 |   at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:450)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like a newbie mistake as the WMS has a tiled cache. i was calling GetCapabilities against the GWC cache instead of the WMS layer

*Incorrect - response excludes text/javascript under GetFeatureInfo*

http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?REQUEST=GetCapabilities

*Correct  - response includes text/javascript under GetFeatureInfo*

http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities

see also 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055196/geoserver-getfeatureinfo-wms-requests-do-not-work-when-using-geowebcache-layer

Answer (score 2):

It does work for me with GeoServer 2.7-beta with Jetty. I tested by two methods.

1. Edit web.xml.

On my computer web.xml had ENABLE_JSON pre-configured but commented out. When I removed the comments around context-parameters and restarted GeoServer I could find a new GetFeatureInfo format from the GetCapabilities: `<Format>text/javascript</Format>`

Corresponding part from my web.xml

> ```
>  <!--Can be true or false (defaults to: false). -->
>   <!--When true the JSONP (text/javascript) output format is enabled -->
>   <!--  I REMOVED THIS LINE AND RESTARTED
>   <context-param>
>     <param-name>ENABLE_JSONP</param-name>
>     <param-value>true</param-value>
>   </context-param>
>   -->   I REMOVED THIS LINE AND RESTARTED
> ```

2. Set global environment variable

Another way to activate JSONP, also mentioned in the documentation http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/global.html#wms-global-variables, is to set an environment variable. On Windows it means giving

```
 set ENABLE_JSONP=true
```

and on Linux

```
export ENABLE_JSONP=true
```

I made a successful test on Windows by adding environment variable into startup.bat without touching web.xml at all.

Comment: really appreciate this and i've since tried both options with no luck on fresh installs of win 8.1 and server 2008 using geoserver 2.6.2 and the 2.7.2 RC1 using JRE 1.7

Answer (score 0):

it works by setting environment variable on windows , just remember to restart the geoserver after you set the variable. I forgot to do this and wasted a lot of time on it.
And strangely, I cannot modify the web.xml file of geoserver 2.6.2.